# PHP contact form reply to mail

Tags: php, email

I've a code where I want my users to mail to my mail, and I should later be able to reply. But It doesn't work for me, It will send it to my mail (my@mail.com). But I also want to be able to respond from my mail client. Which doesn't work for me, it will only reply to myself.

```
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: my@mail.com" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I've tried a lot of different codes nut none of them works.

Comment: The other guys email should be in reply-to

Comment: Yes but then I can't get the email to mysqlf

Comment: What? What are you talking about..?

Comment: You need to clarify the problem, by a lot! Email to `mysqlf`? It appears you want SQL server to receive email, you need POP server to do it.

Comment: When I send the mail, as it is, it gets to my mailserver. But when I send a mail (awnser) it sends a copy to my mail only

Answer (score 2):

> But It doesn't work for me, It will send it to my mail (my@mail.com).
>
> ```
> "Reply-To: my@mail.com" . "\r\n" .
> ```

in fact, your code does exactly what you describe.

If you want to reply to the email of your webuser, you have to specify this in your code. That means, your user has to enter its email address within the web form and you have to pass this variable to the corresponding header field entry.

```
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
```

If the from address and the user email address are equal, you do not necessarily need the reply-to header.